# When should I use Ptr instead of Ref

Tags: julia

Based on the doc,
`Ptr{T}` is

```
A memory address referring to data of type T. However, there is no guarantee that the memory is actually valid, or
  that it actually represents data of the specified type.
```

From the other hand :

```
 Ref{T}

  An object that safely references data of type T. This type is guaranteed to point to valid, Julia-allocated memory
  of the correct type. The underlying data is protected from freeing by the garbage collector as long as the Ref
  itself is referenced.
```

So my question is : `Ref` seems have the same use cases than `Ptr` and seems better than `Ptr` in any cases. Is there some rules on when should we use `Ptr{T}` instead of `Ref{T}` ?

Comment: If you're new to `julia`, most of the time you don't want to use either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful when you're mixing C into Julia (no surprise because the doc page you're referencing is named "C interface"). Like you said, a `Ref` looks like a souped up `Ptr` guaranteed to have valid Julia-allocated memory handled by Julia's garbage collector. `Ptr` is more appropriate for wrapping pointers made and handled on the C side. The guidelines are written in a small section ["When to use T, Ptr{T} and Ref{T}"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#When-to-use-T,-Ptr%7BT%7D-and-Ref%7BT%7D) in the "Calling C and Fortran Code" page:

> In Julia code wrapping calls to external C routines, ordinary (non-pointer) data should be declared to be of type T inside the ccall, as they are passed by value. For C code accepting pointers, Ref{T} should generally be used for the types of input arguments, allowing the use of pointers to memory managed by either Julia or C through the implicit call to Base.cconvert. In contrast, pointers returned by the C function called should be declared to be of output type Ptr{T}, reflecting that the memory pointed to is managed by C only. Pointers contained in C structs should be represented as fields of type Ptr{T} within the corresponding Julia struct types designed to mimic the internal structure of corresponding C structs.

If you're doing pure Julia, you'll want to stick to `Ref`, though you won't need it routinely because references usually show up in mutable objects or struct fields with an abstract type. `Ref` is fairly useful in making an iterable a scalar in broadcasting and wrapping an immutable object in a mutable reference.

Comment: very clear answer, thanks a lot.